# General formula for the sum of these coefficients

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

I have **non-negative** coefficients $a_0, \ldots, a_T$ whose sum is one. I would now like to create new coefficients
$$
b_k \propto a_k\left(1 - \frac{k}{T+1}\right) \qquad k=0, \ldots, T
$$
that also sum up to one. Of course, one way to do so, is to simply divide them by their sum. Since $T$ could be quite large, I wonder if there is a neat expression for the sum
$$
\sum_{k=0}^T b_k = \sum_{k=0}^T a_k\left(1 - \frac{k}{T+1}\right),
$$
so that I can use that in practice. You can simplify this into
$$
\sum_{k=0}^T b_k = 1 - \frac{1}{T+1}\sum_{k=0}^T a_k k
$$
but I couldn't simplify it further.

Comment: A nice idea, but in general there's no way to simplify $\sum ka_k$ given knowledge of $\sum a_k$.

Comment: As above, $S=\sum a_k k$ can take values in $[0, T]$ depending on specific $a_k$.  That said, why do you need to simplify this further, why not calculate / use $S$ as it is? BTW, this isn't one among many ideas, this is the only way to have those proportional coefficients summing to $1$.